# How to set up VOIP soft phone with multiple lines in Ubuntu

Tags: software-recommendation, voip

I am trying to set up a talkback system that allows our radio station to have people calling in. I am looking for a VOIP soft phone that has 4-6 lines that would look something like the below diagram.

I know this might not be normal and I realize that it may not exist, but if anyone knows of any soft phone that would work in Ubuntu I would be interested in checking it out.

[image: VOIP soft phone]

Comment: If this does not relate to Ubuntu, you could try asking it on [Stack Exchange Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions?newreg=644f2ca223894d43a51600e7df318c7d)

Comment: @User24601 We use Ubuntu.